# Adding images as row value in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a json response from the server something like this

```
{"id":20,"name":"d","jobid":"22","workflow":"Diagnostic","**status**":"COMPLETE"}...
```

My js function like this,

```
var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
    'sPaginationType': 'sample',
    "bStateSave": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/someurl"
});​
```

I'm able to display these data in datatable.But
based on the status value in json response , i need to provide **images as datatable row value.**
(say img1 for status 'complete'...)..

I have to do this using jquery to display using jquery datatable.

pls help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply add image in JSON

```
{
    "id": 20,
    "name": "d",
    "jobid": "22",
    "workflow": "Diagnostic",
    "**status**": "<img src=\"img1.jpg\">"
}
```

if you want to switch image based on status. just switch it by conditional statement.

For example :

```
if($status == "complete"){
  $img = "<img src=\"img1.jpg\">";
}
else{
   $img = "<img src=\"img1.jpg\">";
}
```

then build your json using img variable.

Answer (score 0):

Set one of your response variables to a html string.  When you put that html into a cell it should work.